# Bitbucket migrating home directory and fails to start

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server

Today my Bitbucket instance stopped working for some reason. Stop, start and reboot only shows message

> Migrating home directory

Without any progress. It just sits there with the progress bar without doing anything. I don't understand why it is "migrating" the home directory. I'm not upgrading,  changing or anything my instance.

[image]

When I stop and then start the log file shows a few lines of messages and sits at the line that states

```
c.a.s.internal.home.HomeLockAcquirer Successfully acquired lock on home directory /opt/bitbucket-5.15.0/home
```

Is it possible to recover from this error in any way, shape or form? Why is Bitbucket migrating my home directory? What is it waiting for?

```
==> /opt/bitbucket/home/log/atlassian-bitbucket.log <==
2019-02-22 13:40:56,195 INFO  [main]  o.s.boot.SpringApplication 
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.15.RELEASE)


2019-02-22 13:40:56,396 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.b.BitbucketServerApplication Starting BitbucketServerApplication on jupiter with PID 12057 (/opt/bitbucket-5.15.0/app/app/WEB-INF/classes started by bitbucket in /opt/bitbucket-5.15.0/home)
2019-02-22 13:40:56,397 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.b.BitbucketServerApplication No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-02-22 13:40:57,590 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.boot.log.BuildInfoLogger Starting Bitbucket 5.15.0 (bd5e9b4 built on Wed Oct 17 03:20:25 CEST 2018)
2019-02-22 13:40:57,590 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.boot.log.BuildInfoLogger JVM: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_192-b12
2019-02-22 13:40:59,132 INFO  [main]  c.a.b.i.b.BitbucketServerApplication Started BitbucketServerApplication in 3.971 seconds (JVM running for 5.519)
2019-02-22 13:41:01,964 INFO  [spring-startup]  c.a.s.internal.home.HomeLockAcquirer Successfully acquired lock on home directory /opt/bitbucket-5.15.0/home
```

When I stop the service Bitbucket barfs up some error messages. Which suggest that Bitbucket is no longer able to successfully manage its various threads.

```
==> /opt/bitbucket/home/log/launcher.log <==
2019-02-22 13:54:30
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.192-b12 mixed mode):

"localhost-startStop-2" #44 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6570001000 nid=0x485d in Object.wait() [0x00007f65b1759000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c19661c0> (a java.lang.Thread)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
    - locked <0x00000000c19661c0> (a java.lang.Thread)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
    at com.atlassian.johnson.spring.lifecycle.LifecycleDispatcherServlet.destroy(LifecycleDispatcherServlet.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.unload(StandardWrapper.java:1301)
    - locked <0x00000000c18bf930> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.stopInternal(StandardWrapper.java:1635)
    - locked <0x00000000c18bf930> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    - locked <0x00000000c18bf930> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5466)
    - locked <0x00000000c0872398> (a org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    - locked <0x00000000c0872398> (a org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Tomcat-startStop-2" #43 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6520424000 nid=0x485c waiting on condition [0x00007f65b3041000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ccc91900> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:998)
    - locked <0x00000000c0872748> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    - locked <0x00000000c0872748> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Thread-4" #34 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6578348800 nid=0x485b waiting on condition [0x00007f6536b98000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000cca8cbb0> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:998)
    - locked <0x00000000c0872eb0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    - locked <0x00000000c0872eb0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:486)
    - locked <0x00000000c0872eb0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    - locked <0x00000000c08758d8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    - locked <0x00000000c07b26c8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:376)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.stopTomcat(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:256)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.stop(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:310)
    - locked <0x00000000c088ae18> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
    - locked <0x00000000c073b9a8> (a java.lang.Object)

"SIGTERM handler" #42 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f659c001000 nid=0x4859 in Object.wait() [0x00007f65b1c5a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c1965eb0> (a org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
    - locked <0x00000000c1965eb0> (a org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.runHooks(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:107)
    at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks$1.run(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:46)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.runHooks(Shutdown.java:123)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.sequence(Shutdown.java:167)
    at java.lang.Shutdown.exit(Shutdown.java:212)
    - locked <0x00000000c02068b8> (a java.lang.Class for java.lang.Shutdown)
    at java.lang.Terminator$1.handle(Terminator.java:52)
    at sun.misc.Signal$1.run(Signal.java:212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"PostgreSQL-JDBC-SharedTimer-2" #41 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6528f78000 nid=0x2fe9 in Object.wait() [0x00007f6536596000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000ccb8d168> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
    - locked <0x00000000ccb8d168> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue with following database statement

```
 UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED=false, LOCKGRANTED=null, LOCKEDBY=null where ID=1;
```

Notes from Atlassian Community:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/starting-bitbucket-hangs-on-quot-migrating-home-directory-quot/qaq-p/785834

More information https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/bitbucket-server-does-not-start-could-not-acquire-change-log-lock-779171307.html